# Background of child divs do not fill parent div horizontally when x overflows

Tags: html, css

So I have a main div that overflows in the y direction. It is a console that displays each incoming reply in a div with a color-coded background. The problem is on smaller devices the x overflows and the background of these divs do not show in the x overflow. How do I make the background show for the entire x-axis?

```
<div class="console">
   <div v-for="(line, index) in console" :key="index" 
      :style="{ backgroundColor: line.backgroundColor, borderTop: `1px solid ${line.borderColor}`, borderBottom: `1px solid ${line.borderColor}` }" class="p-2">
      <i :class="line.icon" :style="{ color: line.iconColor }" class="mt-1"/>
      <span style="white-space: pre;">{{ line.message }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.console {
  border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin: 8px 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 150px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the child divs do not expand when x overflows.

Comment: You should provide a fiddle or screenshot to make it more clear where the issue is. My first guess would be to set your span to `display: block` and add 100% width. As you didn't provide info on the flex layout of the console it's hard to tell

Comment: @FrankProvost I posted a screenshot, the flex-grow from before wasn't supposed to be there. The layout is as is, I don't use flex in this component, its just an icon and a span in each child div.

Comment: It's not a vue issue, it's an html css issue, and one I've been meaning to ask a question about also. See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/KEbWEa) for additional example. +1